# Cloud Firestore - Python - How to get local timezone in docs streamed with admin sdk

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a real novice in firestore, python and code in general, so apologies in advance. I'm using admin SDK to stream firestore docs into files, and was wondering if it's possible to set a local timezone when I stream the docs.

I know that Firestore just stores the offset from the epoch. When I view it in the console I see my local timezone, and I want to set the same local timezone when I get the docs, but currently get them in UTC.

This is my code:

```
docs = db.collection_group(u'data').stream()   

with open(r'c:\file.txt', 'a') as file:
    for doc in docs:
        file.write(str(doc.to_dict()) + '\n')
```

and I get a file containing all docs as dicts in separate lines, with a UTC timestamp. for example:

```
{'action_name': 'NEW_LEVEL_VALUE', 'new_level': 0, 'timestamp': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2019, 8, 22, 3, 12, 39, 263000, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

I couldn't find any documentation for this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DatetimeWithNanoseconds](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/helpers.html#google.api_core.datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds) is based on [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) from the standard library. The difference is that the standard library doesn't track nanoseconds.

You can use `datetime` methods like [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format the timestamp:

```
docs = db.collection_group(u'data').stream()   

with open(r'c:\file.txt', 'a') as file:
    for doc in docs:
        doc_data = doc.to_dict()
        doc_data['timestamp'] = doc_data['timestamp'].strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")
        file.write(str(doc_data) + '\n')
```

Comment: great! thanks! I found the one I needed to use local time, astimezone(), and used the formatting to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `.to_dict` use the `default=str` option in the `json.dumps()` function:

```py
import json

# Firestore API code to get data 
...

firestoreResult = docRef.get().to_dict()  # DatetimeWithNanoseconds format 

outputWithTimestamp = json.dumps(, indent=4, default=str)
```

All `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` will now show up in the format
`"my_timestamp": "2022-02-26 09:07:47.223000+00:00"`.

Google Firestore example of `to_dict()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document